# Pyplot not plotting data with holes when using lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot list `b` which has several `None` objects in it to represent missing data. When I try to plot it using lines, however, `pyplot` plots nothing. This doesn't happen if I plot it using points. The other set of data, which is complete, plots normally. Below a MWE:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
a=range(10,20)
b=[ el if el%2==0 else None for el in a ]
x=range(10)

plt.plot(x, a, 'o')
plt.plot(x, b, '-')
#plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

Only data from list `a` appears. If I tell `pyplot` to plot it with dots it works. What am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line is drawn between two points, and in matplotlib, both ends need to not be `None` for the line to be drawn.  If you change `b` so that:

```
b=[ el if el%3!=0 else None for el in a ]
```

that is, set every 3rd point to `None`, then you get

[image]

which hopefully makes sense.

Comment: It does make sense, thank you. There is no way around this then?

Comment: I don't think there's any way around the meaning of `None` in this context.  I couldn't really see how `None` could, for example, imply a one sided line from the point because there's no value specified.  Of course, there might still be a way to accomplish whatever your larger goal is.